# mysterious "Object reference not set to an instance of object"

Tags: c#

I understand what the error means but it's quite strange I couldn't possibly think of any reasons,
Here is my simplified structure:

```
 public partial class mainForm : Form
{
    public mainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        IgnoreList = new SortedSet<string>();
        IgnoreListQueue IgnoreQueue = new IgnoreListQueue();
    }
    public class IgnoreListQueue
    {
        private Dictionary<string, int> myQueue;
        public void Add(string s)
        {
        }
        public IgnoreListQueue()
        {
            myQueue = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        }
        public bool contains()
        {}
        ~IgnoreListQueue()
        {
        }
    }
    public SortedSet<string> IgnoreList;
    public IgnoreListQueue IgnoreQueue;
    public int LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        //IgnoreList is fine here
        //IgnoreQueue is null here.
                    //Example:
                    // bool boo = IgnoreQueue.contains(some string);
    }
}
```

In LowLevelKeyboardProc() function, IgnoreQueue was seen as null, and when VS debugged the crash, it really showed IgnoreQueue a null pointer..
As my program hooks Keyboard strokes so I wasn't able to set breakpoint in the LowLevelKeyboardProc() function. However, I was able to breakpoint in the mainForm() constructor and showed that IgnoreQueue was indeed initialized and loaded some data at that point.
Any ideas please ?

Comment: This code won't even compile. Do you have some fields in this form in which you have stored the instances?

Comment: The `IgnoreQueue` variable in the code you posted is a local variable, so of course you can't access it outside the constructor... Is there also a member field called `IgnoreQueue` that you omitted from the example and shadowed in the constructor?

Comment: I forgot to add that both variables mentioned are public variables of the mainForm. All code compiled fine and popped out from intellisense. It only crashes at runtime due to null referencing...

Comment: change this line  IgnoreListQueue IgnoreQueue = new IgnoreListQueue(); to  IgnoreQueue = new IgnoreListQueue(); and try now in the mainform constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a scope issue. IgnoreQueue **declared** within the mainform() constructor and it is not available in the LowLevelKeyboardProc() method. But, IgnoreList is declared in the global level seems and initialized in the constructor.

Comment: Oh mind, i guess I was bleary ... Thank you ! I spent 1 hour looking around for nothing...

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
IgnoreList = new SortedSet<string>();
```

Initialises the member field called `IgnoreList`; but this line:

```
IgnoreListQueue IgnoreQueue = new IgnoreListQueue();
```

Declares and initialises a local variable called `IgnoreQueue`, which is *not the same* as the member field with the same name. The member field will still be `null` after this.

Since you actually want initialise the other member field you need to do this instead:

```
IgnoreQueue = new IgnoreListQueue();
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are not actually initializing the member variable 'IgnoreQueue' of mainForm  class , but you are creating a local instance of IgnoreListQueue in the constructor which will not be available to other member functions.

Ideally your constructor should be like this

```
 public mainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.IgnoreList = new SortedSet<string>();
        this.IgnoreQueue = new IgnoreListQueue();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public mainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        IgnoreList = new SortedSet<string>();
        IgnoreQueue = new IgnoreListQueue(); //no new declaration, this will set the public IgnoreListQueue you define later.
    }
```

It's recommended to declare class fields before the constructor though, to improve readability. Also you should consider making them `private`, you should **never** declare instance variables as `public`.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is down to the scope of variables, and relates to the IgnoreQueue. Lets take a look at the code and see what's going on:

```
public IgnoreListQueue IgnoreQueue;
public mainForm()  
{
    InitializeComponent();
    IgnoreList = new SortedSet<string>();
    IgnoreListQueue IgnoreQueue = new IgnoreListQueue();
}
```

Within your constructor you define a new variable, IgnoreQueue and instantiate it. Although this shares the same name as the property on your class, it isn't the same variable. Instead the variable scope is restricted to your constructor. This means when you try to use the propert later, it's null, hence your NullReferenceException.

You might also notice, that IgnoreList isn't re-defined in the constructor, which is why that works later on. The easiest way to fix this, is to remove the IgnoreListQueue part within the constructor, to make it match IgnoreList:

```
IgnoreQueue = new IgnoreListQueue();
```

However a better approach is to use the, **this** keyword, which would have helped you spot your problem straight away.

```
public IgnoreListQueue IgnoreQueue;
public mainForm()  
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.IgnoreList = new SortedSet<string>();
    this.IgnoreQueue = new IgnoreListQueue();
}
```